# как перносить текст без пробелов в таблице

Tags: html, css

Таблица находится в блоке `div` который занимает 87% от всей странице в таблице указано `width='100%'` если ввести много текста без пробелов в `td` то таблица выйдет из рамок блока. Как сделать что бы текст переносился и таблица не выходила за рамки `div`'а

Comment: как насчет примера кода?

Comment: @NeedHate Мне кажется я всё детально розписал

Comment: @BedOmar `css:

word-break: break-all;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А это к чему к div или p или для table или td?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский напишыте этот ответ я выберу его он мне помого!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам помогут свойства [table-layout](https://webref.ru/css/table-layout) и [word-wrap](https://webref.ru/css/word-wrap).

```css
.example-area {
  width: 87%;
  background: #efefef;
}
.example-tbl {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; /* ! */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* ! */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.example-tbl td {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-area">
  <table class="example-tbl">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="40%" />
      <col width="25%" />
      <col />
    </colgroup>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>this is</td>
        <td>example</td>
        <td>table</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</td>
        <td>Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch</td>
        <td>ANTICONSTITUTIONNELLEMENT</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ваш код робочий но главная сторчка котрая мне помогла это word-wrap: break-word;